# How to record cycling distance using M9 coprocessor without GPS

Tags: applications, gps, health-kit, iphone

I have an iPhone 6s.  It automatically records steps and walking distance in the Health app using the M9 motion coprocessor with very little battery impact.  How can I record cycling distance like this?  All the apps I find on the App Store for cycling seem to use GPS, which drains the battery quickly.

I should also mention:  After cycling, the Health app shows an increased number of steps, but I have no idea how cycling mileage correlates to step count.

Comment: I believe the M9 estimates walking distance by counting steps and deriving an estimated pace length from your height. Since counting steps can be done using the device gyroscope alone, this uses little battery. Cycling cannot be estimated so easily from device motion and must be measured by GPS.

Comment: What if you put the iPhone in an ankle band?

Comment: Ha! That's a nice idea, unfortunately one up/down motion of a leg doesn't equate to a fixed distance travelled when riding a bike with changeable gears, or a freewheel even. If you were riding a single speed fixed wheel bike, you could make this approach work i guess!

Comment: Ah, good point.  I guess the phone would have to be mounted on the wheel somehow.